# How to compare 2 Xcode targets

Tags: xcode

How would I compare the differences between two targets of the same project in Xcode? I'd like to see the differences in the source, and perhaps build-info too.

Comment: I've just finished ruby tool to compare list of files in Xcode targets. Hope it may help you. https://github.com/smirn0v/xcode-same-targets

Comment: Funny- I have a similar project on node http://staxmanade.com/2015/02/how-to-diff-two-xcode-targets/

Answer (score 41):

You can compare the build settings by selecting both target then 'levels'

[image: Compare targets]

As far as im aware, there is no easy way to compare what source files are included in each target.

Comment: Thanks! If only Apple would split up the mega-huge xcodeproj file and have separate files for each target...

Answer (score 6):

It's an old topic, however I just had the same need and found an easy way to compare targets.

I noticed that in "Build Settings" tab, you can select one or more lines and copy the selection, the result being a simple text composed of paragraphs with key/values lines in the form :
key = value
and a header like :
//:configuration = Debug

Select all settings for a given Target with a simple cmd+a, copy the settings in a text file, repeat the action for the second target and simply compare text files with FileMerge or your preferred diff app.

Note : pay extra care to diffs concerning the headers, then the whole paragraph may be considered as different.